# Loyalty reward - record for every day of a week

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains every login a user makes. I am trying to make a loyalty system that rewards users if they've logged in every day for a week.

So, the real question, how do I get every record in a set week by a user (user_id) and know that there was a login on each day? Would MySQL be able to do this or would I have to do a query for every user and then further processing on top of that?

The only thing I can think of doing is:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`time_they_logged_in` = IN WEEK X

<?php

$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT....');
$result->bindParam(1, etc etc);

$logged_in_on = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

foreach($result->fetchAll() as $login_record) {
    if(LOGGED IN DAY = MONDAY -> $logged_in[0] = true)
}
```

Idea: record for each week, with a column for each day and a total - then it's a matter of updating it on viewing a page / login and then looking for items with a total of 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe.

```
SELECT count(distinct date(time_they_logged_in)) 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`time_they_logged_in` between now()-interval 7 day and now();
```

If the count is 7 they logged in at least once per day in the past week.

Comment: I did think of that, but I need to know that the user was logged in on all days of the week - not just at least 7 times.

Comment: The `COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(...` means you'll get 1 added to the count for each distinct day they log in.

Comment: Proves how little I now about SQL. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: There are actually **8 dates** between `now()-interval 7 day` and `now()`

Comment: It might be better with `BETWEEN currentdate()-interval 6 day AND now()`

Comment: I think you mean curdate(), but typos aside why would that be 'better' than now()?  I guess it depends on the semantics of how the OP wants it to operate but now includes the time of day as well

Comment: @atxba: `DATE(NOW))` is the same as `CURDATE()` or `CURRENT_DATE()` (my mistake, I missed the underscore). But my main point was that `7` should probably be `6`.

Comment: The better was because `time_they_logged_in between now()-interval 7 day and now()` means that if now it's `16:00` and the user logged 7 days ago at `11:00`, that login won't be counted. And you are right, that depends on what the OP wants.